# JSN SR04 not giving correct readings when connected to ESP32?

Tags: power, sensor, buck, ultrasound, distance

When I connect a [JSNSR04](https://www.makerguides.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/JSN-SR04T-Datasheet.pdf) to ESP32 and power it with USB of my computer, I am able to get correct readings.

[image]

---

But when I power it with buckconverter for short distances ( <150) JSN gives correct readings but for long distances JSN gives error readings.

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the problem you see? The pulse length you get is just wrong? Have you checked to quality of the supply voltage? Do you have a scope to check the ripple?

Comment: @jusaca I don't have scope. So I can't check quality of supply voltage.  But assuming that supply voltage might be the problem how it be corrected?

Comment: Try putting a capacitor (~10uF)  between 5V and GND right at the supply pins of the ESP and the JSN. Could you maybe add a photo of your wiring?

Comment: @jusaca I am using jumper wires.

Comment: That might be the problem, the long wires in addition to a maybe not that clean supply voltage can cause these problems. Can you try using nice short wires instead?

Comment: @jusaca When I connect earth and the ground of circuit, everything works exactly fine. Can I proceed with this or is it not the correct way?

Comment: Earth and ground? You are bypassing the galvanic insulation of the power adapter?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96845/discussion-between-sreedhar-reddy-a-c-and-jusaca).

Answer (score 1):

If your JSN SR04 has `2.0` written on the board, you should put a pull-up resistor on the `echo` pin. It could be a 10k resistor.

Comment: @dalmango Tried this but it did not help.